# Creating nested or hierarchically indexed tables in Matlab r2017b

Tags: matlab, dataframe

I would like to create a table with hierarchical indexing in Matlab R2017b.

It would look like a pandas dataframe in Python with hierarchical columns, e.g.,:

```
                 bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
          one       three       one       two       one       seven       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412  2.565646  1.431256  1.340309 -1.170299 -0.226169
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678  1.130127 -1.436737
C      -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372  0.974466 -2.006747
```

Is this possible?  If so, how would I access the column associated with say baz, two?

Comment: Each column of a `table` can have multiple "columns", but these don't have names. See the example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html#btw1wrc-3), where the "BloodPressure" column has two columns of data.

Comment: OK.  But in my case I'd need explicit column labels for the diastolic and systolic pressure values under the blood pressure column.

Comment: Use a struct instead... or firmly establish *why* you're trying to arrange data like this to see if there's a better way - this hierarchy is probably going to be less performant and involve uglier to code

Answer (score 3):

You can make nested tables in R2017b, like so:

```
t = table(table(rand(3,1), rand(3,1), 'VariableNames', {'one', 'three'}), ...
    table(rand(3,1), rand(3,1), 'VariableNames', {'one', 'two'}), ...
    'VariableNames', {'bar', 'baz'}, 'RowNames', {'A', 'B', 'C'})
```

In R2017b, the display isn't amazing, like this:

```
t =
  3×2 table
             bar            baz    
         ___________    ___________
    A    [1x2 table]    [1x2 table]
    B    [1x2 table]    [1x2 table]
    C    [1x2 table]    [1x2 table]
```

but in R2018b it's better:

```
t =
  3×2 table
                bar                   baz        
           one       three       one        two  
         __________________    __________________
    A    0.81472    0.91338     0.2785    0.96489
    B    0.90579    0.63236    0.54688    0.15761
    C    0.12699    0.09754    0.95751    0.97059
```

In either version, you can access the nested table variables using `t.bar.one` etc.